# else: syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, if-statement

I am a little new to python and I am trying to write this script to cancel print jobs over 1 mb.. (the line where it is checking for size is set to 1 mb just to make sure it is working).  for some reason my last else statement keeps saying it has invalid syntax.  I checked to see if all parentheses were closed and I could not find an unmatched pair.  could someone please tell me why it says it is invalid? Also can you take a look at my line 24 (fullname = ...grep...) to make sure the syntax on that is correct?

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os

infile = open ('test.pl', 'r')

outfile = open('print.reportpython', 'w+')

newfile = infile.readlines()

newfile.pop(0)

count = 0

firstline = newfile[0]

splitline = firstline.split()

currentuser = splitline[1]

currentuser = str(currentuser)

for line in newfile:

  newline = line.split()

  names = newline[1]

  size = int(newline[2])

  names = str(names)

  print names

  if names is currentuser:

    if size >= 1:

      os.popen ("cancel lab01-10292")

  fullname = os.popen("cat /etc/passwd |grep " + newline[1] + "cut -d':' -f5")

  count += 1

  print count

  else:

    print outfile.write ("(" + currentuser + ")")

    print outfile.write (" ")

    count = 0

    currentuser = names
```

Comment: Check the indentation!

Comment: I have checked it. I even deleted all the spaces on the lines around it and readded them as all spaces to make sure there weren't any hidden tabs

Comment: Don't put a space between each line.

Comment: Can you image that there is bug in else statement?

Comment: ooh wow.. thanks. I don't know how I missed that. now my other problem is my 

fullname = os.popen("cat /etc/passwd |grep " + newline[1] + "cut -d":" -f5")

it says it is invalid syntax at the ":"
i also changed the ':' above to ":"

Comment: If you now have a completely different problem, ask a separate question

Answer (score 5):

You do:

```
if foo:
  bar
baz
else:
  bomb
```

Which is wrong. All the lines between the `if` and its corresponding `else` must be indented deeper than the `if` and `else`, like this:

```
if foo:
  bar
  baz
else:
  bomb
```

Answer (score 3):

The `else` is at the same indentation as the previous line, but the statement on the previous line doesn't have an `else` clause. Fix your indentation.

Comment: ooh wow.. thanks. I don't know how I missed that. now my other problem is my 

fullname = os.popen("cat /etc/passwd |grep " + newline[1] + "cut -d":" -f5")

it says it is invalid syntax at the ":"
i also changed the ':' above to ":"